Representing an 8-digit hexadecimal as a long
I am writing a Java program that performs bitwise operations on bites in a data stream.
I have been given test values in the form of 8-digit hexadecimal strings, which I have converted to base 10 and hard-coded as values of long data type.
These are the base-10 versions of the hexadecimal strings, but are too large for the long data type, though the compiler complains they are too large for type int. The signature of the function I am to write also involves a long data version of an 8-digit hexadecimal.
Here is the hex numbers written in base 10:
  static byte[] crypt(byte[] data, long initialValue) {

        // byte [] outputData = new byte[data.length];

        long s = (long) 4294967295;

        long f = (long) 2271560481;
 }

error message:
The literal 4294967295 of type int is out of range 
The literal 2271560481 of type int is out of range 

What is a better way to take hex values or strings and convert them to acceptable data type with that length.

Java allows you to write int (and long) values using hex notation: 0x12345678 and 0x123456789abcdefL

(long) 4294967295 is casting the int literal to long, but 4294967295 is an invalid int... try long s = 4294967295L (a long literal, no cast needed) -- sure, IMO, the better way to take hex values is as given in previous comment (if given as string: Long.parseLong() or Long.parseUnsignedLong())
